# RestSharp fail to authenticate with Django Rest Framework

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to consume an API in Djnago with basic authentication.
I've tested the API successfully in Chrome's rest client tool. But I cannot make the same API call with RestSharp, it always return:

```
{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

If I lift the authentication in Django with setting: `'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),` it works, but then there is no authentication, which can't be a solution.

Here is the code for RestSharp:

```
        var client = new RestClient(host);

        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password);

        var request = new RestRequest(service, Method.GET);

        var response = client.Execute(request) as RestResponse;

        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

I'm not sure if this need to be fix on Django side or RestSharp side.
Is there any additional request header needed for RestSharp's request?
Or is it a configuration on Django?

Comment: I'm having the same issue using selenium, so presumably this has to do with the request sent by django, and not actually being logged in. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I've changed to rebuild everything in python. But did you exam the case in @Richard's answer? that is one sure case lead to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Look at your url mapping, 
Possibly you need make your name ends with a '/'. 
E.g. 
you need change below code from:

```
request.Resource = "myinfo";
```

to:

```
request.Resource = "myinfo/";
```

It might be caused it doesn't handle redirects correctly. Using the correct url should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not for my case, the mapping is correct. Maybe it's server config problem, it works well in my local with django's "runserver".

Comment: can you post the value of the variable "service" in your code example? I met exactly the same issue as you which I solved by appending a '/' to the service. Django will redirects requests without a trailing slash to the url with a slash appended. Restsharp doesn't foward the login credentials with the redirection which results the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the kind of authentication.  You're using "session" kind authentication, so you have to login first, and store your session cookie

example:

```
 private RestClient RestCliente = new RestClient("http://yoursiteurl.com");

    private CookieContainer SessionCookie = new CookieContainer();

     private void ServiceSession() // once per session only
        {
            RestRequest login = new RestRequest("/api-auth/login/", Method.POST); // path to your login on rest-framework
            RestCliente.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");


            IRestResponse loginresponse = RestCliente.Execute(login);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var cookie = loginresponse .Cookies.FirstOrDefault();
                SessionCookie.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, cookie.Domain));

            }

            RestCliente.CookieContainer = SessionCookie;


        }
```

then, you can simply request your info

example:

```
private void InfoRequest()
    {
        RestRequest infoneeded= new RestRequest("/info/path/?format=json", Method.GET);

        IRestResponse response = RestCliente.Execute(infoneeded);

        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    }
```